# How to retrive only parent child and enable expand to get the child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

Need to load only the parent node for the sake of performance and then load the children when the user clicks on the icon, and the icon does not seem to expand when I do not carry child node. Can anyone help me?

My code return in json. below:

```
"JsonData": [
  {
    "id": "13",
    "text": "MainBox",
    "parent": "#",
    "state": {
      "opened": false,
      "disabled": false,
      "selected": false
    },
    "children": false,
    "icon": null,
    "li_attr": "{class = 'jstree-leaf' }",
    "a_attr": null
  }
]
```

**EDIT**
My jquery below:

```
root = $('#tree-files').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': //code before       
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu"]
   });
```

Comment: Where's your jQuery code? Not sure what you're going for

Comment: @tymeJV i edited my code, my code not have a error, but i can't do the feature of  open child node

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. i hope be help for someone.

```
root = $('#tree-files').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': function (node) {
                    return 'Action/Controller';
                },
                'headers': headers,
                'xhrFields': { withCredentials: true },
                'async': true,
                'data': function (node) {   
                    //handler params here
                    return { 'id': node.id } ;
                },
                success: function (dados) {
                    //code success here
                }
            },
            "check_callback": true,
            "themes": {
                "theme": "default",
                "dots": false,
                "icons": true,
            },
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu", "crrm"]
        });
```